# Why does Mathematica return Indeterminate for this converging infinite sum?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

```
Limit[Sum[k/(n^2 - k + 1), {k, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

This should converge to `1/2`, but `Mathematica` simply returns `Indeterminate` without calculating (or so it would appear). Any specific reason why it can't handle this? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: That's because `Sum[k/(n^2 - k + 1), {k, 1, n}] // FullSimplify` is itself problematic.

Comment: I see. Would there be a better way to evaluate such an infinite sum in `Mathematica`?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [Euler-Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) formula to get the limit (the sum can be approximated by an integral, which becomes exact in the infinite limit):

```
f[i_] = i/(n^2 - i + 1);
Integrate[f[k], {k, 0, n}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
Limit[%, n -> Infinity]
```

> `1/2`

Answer (score 9):

Reverse the order of the summation. i.e., `k -> (n - k + 1)`

```
s = Sum[(n - k + 1)/(n^2 - (n - k + 1) + 1), {k, 1, n}] // Simplify

(*  -n + (1 + n^2) PolyGamma[0, 1 + n^2] - (1 + n^2) PolyGamma[0, 1 - n + n^2]  *)

Limit[s, n -> Infinity]

(*  1/2  *)
```

For an alternative representation

```
s2 = FullSimplify[s]

(*  -n - (1 + n^2) HarmonicNumber[(-1 + n) n] + (1 + n^2) HarmonicNumber[n^2]  *)

Limit[s2, n -> Infinity]

(*  1/2  *)
```

Comment: So without reversing the order you get internally garbage which as NLimit warns has 1/0^1 which leads to Indeterminate: NLimit[(1 + n) HurwitzLerchPhi[1, 1, n - n^2] + 
  Hypergeometric2F1[2, -n^2, 1 - n^2, 1]/n^2 + 
  Hypergeometric2F1[2, 1 + n - n^2, 2 + n - n^2, 1]/(1 + n - n^2), 
 n -> Infinity]

Answer (score 5):

In cases where you can't get a symbolic result, it's also possible to use a completely numerical approach:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

sum[n_?NumberQ] := NSum[k/(n^2 - k + 1), {k, 1, n}]
NLimit[sum[n], n -> Infinity]

(* ==> 0.499999 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that without the limit, the sum doesn't converge, and without the sum the limit is `0`. *Mathematica* can only do one at a time.

At a finite value `n`, the sum gives a sequence with a $\frac{1}{0}$ or other complexinfinity expression for all values of `n`, which is a by product of the sum not converging.

You can approximate the limit:

```
i=4;
Sum[k/(n^2 - k + 1), {k, 1, 10*^i}] /. n -> 10*^i // N
```

which will give `i` significant numbers.