# Why won't Limit evaluate, and what can be done about it

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt{n}{{n}\choose {[np + \sqrt{np(1-p)}]}}p^{[np + \sqrt{np(1-p)}]}(1-p)^{(n-[np + \sqrt{np(1-p)}])}$$ where $0<p<1$ and $[\cdot ]$ denotes the nearest integer (if it greatly simplifies things at no cost, I don't mind if $[\cdot]$ is removed):

```
Limit[Sqrt[n ] Binomial[n, Round[n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]]] p^
Round[n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]] (1 - p)^(
n -  Round[n p - Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]] ), n -> Infinity]
```

Mathematica (version 11.0, Student Edition) gives the input as the answer. This limit is of the type $0\times \infty$.

In hopes of simplifying things, I removed the nearest integer function in both of the exponents, but the same issue occurs:

```
Limit[Sqrt[n ] Binomial[n, Round[n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]]] p^(
n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]) (1 - p)^(n -  n p - Sqrt[n p (1 - p)] ), 
n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1]
```

Other Ideas: (1) I tried computing limits of products separately, but $\sqrt{n}p^{np + \sqrt{np(1-p)}}\to 0$ while the remaining product tends ComplextInfinity.

(2) I tried using bounds on the binomial coeffiecient: ${{a}\choose{b}}\le \frac{a^b}{b!}\le (\frac{a *e}{b})^b$, but the same issue occurs here when I use either of these upper bounds in place of the binomial coefficient:

```
Limit[Sqrt[n ] (n ^(n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)])/
Gamma[1 + n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]]) p^(
n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]) (1 - p)^(n -  n p - Sqrt[n p (1 - p)] ), 
n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1]
```

and

```
Limit[Sqrt[n ] ((n E)/(n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]))^(
n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]) p^(n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]) (1 - p)^(
n -  n p - Sqrt[n p (1 - p)] ), n -> Infinity, 
Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1]
```

Follow up: Is there other software that is better at evaluating limits?

Comment: Judging from the interpolation function I made of this, I don't think there's an answer to be honest.

Comment: @Feyre .5? Are you getting that from your interpolation? Can you post the code for what you did?

Comment: Oh, that was with later code, the original code tends clearly to 0. Just try `tab = Table[{p, 
     Sqrt[n] Binomial[n, Round[n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]]] p^
       Round[n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]] (1 - p)^(n - 
         Round[n p - Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]])} /. n -> 10^7, {p, 0.01, 
    0.99, 0.01}];`,`ListPlot[tab, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Make sure you seperate the two codes, first the tab=table[], then in different line the Listplot[]

Comment: Thanks, turn this into an answer if you'd like. Can you explain intuitively how you see the limit is 0? I see how it is 0 times infinity, but the binomial coefficient is growing very fast.

Comment: You can intuit it from the fact that `Limit[Binomial[n, n] p^n, n -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1]` goes to zero, so the exponential term must grow the fastest.

Comment: Related: [Why does Mathematica return Indeterminate for this converging infinite sum?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120808/why-does-mathematica-return-indeterminate-for-this-converging-infinite-sum)

Comment: @Feyre I don't think that's the same since Binomial[n,n]=1 whereas Binomial[n, np + sqrt[np(1-p]] tends to infinity.

Comment: To answer the letter of the question, if not the spirit: `Limit[]` is choking because it is internally trying to perform an expansion in $n$ about $\infty$, and then trying to take the constant term of that series, which it fails to do.

Comment: maybe try math.stackexchange, it might be enlightening to learn how to formally,rigorously take the limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we remove `Round`, `Series` (around $n\to\infty$) does the trick:

```
$Assumptions = n \[Element] Integers && n > 2 && 0 < p < 1;
Series[Sqrt[n] Binomial[n,(n p+Sqrt[n p(1-p)])] p^(n p+Sqrt[n p(1-p)])(1-p)^(n-(n p-Sqrt[n p(1-p)])), {n, Infinity, 0}]
Simplify[%] // Normal
Limit[%, n -> \[Infinity]]
(*0*)
```

This works for all $0<p<1$. For $p\equiv0$,

```
Limit[Sqrt[n] Binomial[n,(n p+Sqrt[n p(1-p)])] p^(n p+Sqrt[n p(1-p)]) (1-p)^(n-(n p-Sqrt[n p(1-p)])), p -> 0]
(*Sqrt[n]*)
```

and therefore the limit diverges (the exact same thing happens for $p\equiv 1$).

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by "around $n \to \infty$?" Does that mean that the center of the series is changing? If so, are we still allowed to apply the divergence test to my sequence in that case?

Comment: @TheSubstitute around $n\to\infty$ means that we execute `Series[...,{n,∞,0}]`. In more mathematical terms, $f(n)\overset{n\to\infty}=f(\infty)+\mathcal O(1/n)$.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`NLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NLimit.html)

```
expr = Sqrt[n] *
   Binomial[n, Round[n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]]] *
   p^Round[n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]] *
   (1 - p)^(n - Round[n p - Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]]);

Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];

Table[
  {p, NLimit[expr, n -> Infinity,
       WorkingPrecision -> #] & /@
     {15, 20, 25}} // Flatten,
  {p, 1/10, 9/10, 1/20}] // Grid
```

[image]

Increasing the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) produces progressively smaller values which supports the `Limit` being zero.

Comment: although this is very helpful, I really want to see if the limit is 0 for all $p$ in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `Limit` works if you just get rid of the Round.

```
Limit[Sqrt[n] Binomial[n, n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]] 
   p^(n p + Sqrt[n p (1 - p)]) (1 - p)^(n - (n p - Sqrt[n p (1 - p)])),
   n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1]
```

> 0

Note for p near zero the limit is approached very slowly (just looking at it numerically)

Comment: When I enter this into Mathematica (11.0, student edition), the output is the same as the input.

Comment: 10.1 here, must be a version issue.

Comment: It now prints that Limit cannot be followed.